# nginx path routing for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, create-react-app

i need help with routing react app to a directory path with nginx

right now everything works perfect serving react app on `example.com/` but what i want to do is serve the same app on `example.com/v1/`

i have tried many things but nothing works so hoping to get some help here

here is what i have tried with my nginx configuration

```
upstream react_v1 {
    server react_v1:3000;
}
upstream api_v1 {
    server api_v1:4000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;  
    location /v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://react_v1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location ^~ /v1/api/ {
        rewrite ^/v1/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api_v1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

i also setup env `PUBLIC_URL=https://example.com/v1` and even tried the homepage thing by editing `package.json` file and adding `"homepage": "http://example.com/v1",`

issue is the js and images do not get rendered even though they return 200
i just see blank pages

question here is this.

how can one route nginx for a react app to listen on a directory path?

Comment: So when you try to access `https://.../v1`, you get a 200? If that's the case, the issue is probably not with nginx.

Comment: yes 200...issue is not nginx as i am able to route the `/v1/api/` fine with no issue for another api app...so issue is with react to work with changing all urls to be `/v1/` and what i tried did not work